# Passing a variable into the standard filter using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am trying to create a filter that works the same way as the built in angular filter in HTML but takes in a variable instead of a specific value.

E.g. In my html file I have something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat = "item in Items | filter:{function:'1300'}"> 
  <td>[[item.name]]</td>
</tr>
```

but I want to be able to pass in a variable instead of '1300' whose value is defined when the user clicks on a button (the button is linked to a specific value).

I was trying to recreate the built in filter function in a filter.js file and call it in my controller to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/mobideje/1/):

```
<tr ng-repeat = "item in Items | filter:{function:theFilter}"> 
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

And have your buttons like this:

```
<button ng-click="setFilter(1300)">1300</button>
<button ng-click="setFilter(1400)">1400</button>
<button ng-click="setFilter(1200)">1200</button>
```

And your controller method like this:

```
$scope.setFilter = function(filter) {
    $scope.theFilter = filter;
}
```